# How to integrate audio recording in my PHP application or give me any idea regarding that type of application?

Tags: php

I want to integrate voice recording in my PHP application?

Can anybody help me regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

Kanji

Comment: PHP or HTML will not have any control of the user's microphone, but Flash will.

Comment: Or a JavaApplet (if anyone still uses these nowadays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with only PHP (which handle SERVER, not client part ^^)

To record audio, you need an Flash || Java App (depends what you prefer...) Or maybe HTML5... I don't know if it works but may be a better way ^^

But remember that after it depends on the client computer and you mayb have difficulties or cases to handle ^^

But If you google it you will find some answers :
http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/173652-record-audio-using-php.html

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is any ready made tools of flash to control user's microphone?